# Problem with launching build app on Iphone via Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem trying to run a compiled app on a real iPhone device through Xcode. When I try to start, I get a message:

> is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to “Apple Development” in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

My application uses ionic, cordova. Xcode quietly sees the device. In the Xcode section: “Signing & Capabilities -> Signing -> Team” I set my developer account. I also tried changing from “iOS Developer” to “Apple Developer” in the “Build Settings -> Code Signing Entitlements” section, but it still didn’t fix the problem. Tell me, what could be the cause of the error? And what else needs to be additionally configured to run the compiled application on a real device?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with ionic, you need a development certificate for that app. Your app has a package name (ex: com.mycompany.myapp), that app ID must be registered in Apple (https://developer.apple.com), then you need to open XCode and log in with the same account with which you created the app ID.

If you mark Automatic signing, Apple should handle the rest for you (creating a development certificate and all) so you will be able to just run your app. However, if you choose manual signing, you'll have to go to developer.apple.com -> certificates -> create a new development certificate for that app -> download it -> double click to add that certificate to your Mac -> then run in xcode.

By the way, XCode has an annoying bug since a long time ago, where sometimes it does not detect the automatic signing and displays an error (a red little message). If you switch to manual signing and then return to automatic signing, it should disappear.